# Le « mouvement TradWife » et les « tradwives » : emprunt intégral avec indices ou néologisme ?

Tags: anglais, néologismes, emprunts, majuscules

J'ai lu un [article](https://www.cnn.com/2022/12/27/us/tradwife-1950s-nostalgia-tiktok-cec/index.html) discutant d'une subculture marginale sur internet (« These millennials and zoomers glamorize the aesthetics of 1950s Americana [...] ») récupérée plus récemment, celle des « tradwives » (raccourci/mot-valise pour *traditional [wife](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/wife)/housewife*) ; on dit du terme qu'il est hautement associé à la suprématie blanche ([*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tradwife#Usage_notes)). Sur [*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tradwife) on trouve l'emprunt intégral *tradwife* qu'on définit comme une « femme, pratiquante du mouvement TradWife, soumise à son mari, n’ayant pas d’emploi et s’occupant du foyer, en comparaison des femmes des années 50 » et on a un article complet sur le sujet sur [*Wikipédia*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tradwife).

Je remarque qu'en français sur Wiktionnaire on a employé une majuscule à *wife* (mouvement Trad**W**ife) qu'on ne trouve nulle part en anglais.

- Est-ce un procédé courant en français, connaît-on d'autres exemples,
  et que pense-t-on de sa valeur pour aider le locuteur francophone à
  identifier les composants du mot-valise ?
- Vu l'imprécision du terme et sa récupération ( « While there are some
  tradwives, including women of color, who simply hold conservative
  beliefs on the roles men and women should occupy in relationships
  [...] some on the alt right use tradwife aesthetics to recruit White
  women into the movement. Such influencers promote a contempt for
  modernity and feminism, as well as “a desire for an idealized and
  implicitly coded White past [...]. », Annie Kelly, ds l'article sur
  CNN), son inadéquation si une personne de sexe masculin voulait s'en prévaloir (il n'a assurément pas une telle vocation dans l'esprit de ceux qui y font référence) et de surcroît son appropriation de l'idée de *tradition(nel)*,
  dispose-t-on d'un meilleur néologisme/mot-valise pour représenter la
  personne qui s'identifie à cette subculture marginale voire à sa
  récupération récente ?

Comment: Peut-être *ménagère au foyer*.

Answer (score 1):

Pour la majuscule, je penche pour une influence du monde des nouvelles technologies. Soit par l'entremise des *hashtags* Twitter qui sont souvent faits de mots accolés "capitalisés" pour plus de lisibilité (l'article cité dans Wiktionnaire mentionne le hashtag #TradWife). Soit par habitude de l'auteur du wiki, la mise en relief [par majuscules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) étant une des manières traditionnelles de rendre plus lisibles les chaînes de caractères faites d'un agglomérat de mots en informatique.

Dans les deux cas, cela ne me semble pas nécessaire puisque c'est un *portmanteau* et non deux mots séparés en anglais, et il est assez simple et court pour être compréhensible sans signe distinctif de début de mot.

Je ne vois pas de néologisme correspondant à la même idée en français.

Answer (score 1):

Uniquement concernant le néologisme, je pense à l'emploi du préfixe [*rétro-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9tro-), productif, évoquant *en arrière*, voire *rétrograde*, couplé avec un élément de suggestion en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51981/le-mouvement-tradwife-et-les-tradwives-emprunt-int%C3%A9gral-avec-indices-o#comment107893_51981) et des termes usuels décrivant de liens interpersonnels tributaires d'une institution ou autrement :

> Mouvement rétro-[ménager](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9nager/1).
>  Rétro-époux/épouse.
> [masculin/féminin unis par les liens du mariage]
>  Rétro-partenaire.
> [unisexe]

On a aussi d'autres préfixes qui peuvent être utiles en combinaison avec ce qui précède, dont [*auto-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/auto-) « de soi-même », précisant que c'est un choix et non une circonstance ; [*simili-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/simili-) pour l'idée d'*imitation*, soulignant possiblement l'intention de reproduire ; et peut-être bien même [*archéo-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arch%C3%A9o-), pour la référence à la « préhistoire ».

> Auto-archéo-simili-rétro...

Ces préfixes et termes usuels bien adaptés et productifs permettent de débusquer le « tradwife » et de mieux le comprendre ou le préciser afin  d'éviter de devenir prisonnier d'une pseudo-compréhension d'un terme en langue étrangère à laquelle nous force l'emprunt intégral.